# Implementing Google + with Youtube API files already present

Tags: ios, youtube, google-plus

A couple of weeks back, I implemented the YouTube API for iOS. This worked fine, and I can do everything I need to do via YouTube. Now I am looking to implement Google+. [Following this guide](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in), I have copied the frameworks into my project. However, I am getting hundreds of compiler duplicate and redefinition errors, all concerning my Header files (which are in my project).

Obviously the GoogleOpenSource.framework has the same files, such as **GTMHTTPFetcher.h** and **GTLQuery**, and the compiler is throwing up errors at the redefinitions. I think understand this.

What I don't understand is how I'm going to get around this problem. Previous to attempting to install google+ I had my header files under my project like so:

[image]

I didnt think this was the correct way to leave the files, but it worked so I left it. Its only until now that its causing major problems. I was really hazy as to installing the YouTube API and I stopped on whatever worked. Under my project I have this before my files:

[image]

And the framework added header files (that I cant delete), like so:

[image].

**What I tried**

At first I tried to delete the header files originally in my project, left over from the youtube implementation. The compiler just sent me a ton of warnings about how the files such as **GTLQuery** and **GTMHTTPFetcher** were missing from the project, despite them being in the framework header files.

So. I am aware I may implemented my YouTube stuff in a skewed way to start with, but I'm really confused by this and dont want to mess it up much more! My questions are:

- How should I change my implementation?
- What should I change to get rid of all the duplicate errors when adding the G+ frameworks?

Sorry if this seems stupid and counter-intuitive, but I found the installation of the YouTube API really problematic and this is what seemed to work. 
Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I am getting hundreds of compiler duplicate and redefinition errors :(

Comment: This was a while ago now, but I seem to remember just having a big clean of my project files and organisation then identified what I was missing. Turned out to be a couple of the HTTPSomething files. (Sorry if this is not much help!)